# How do you properly notate $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}$?

Tags: notation, continued-fractions

I want to write $\frac{1}{x+n}$ where $n=\frac{1}{x+n}$. My current solution is $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}$. Is this a proper notation?

I noticed that this is also equal to $\frac{x(...)+1}{x(x(...)+1)+1}$. Is there a proper way to notate this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations for the various notations used.  This is a "continued fraction".

Comment: No, the correct way to notate that term is by using the limit of a sequence. Let $t_{n+1} = \frac{1}{x + t_{n}}$ where $t_0 = y$ (some arbitrary real). Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n$ if it exists, equals $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}$; and if the limit does not exist, then this quantity has no meaning whatsoever.

Comment: Actually as say @Anon you can write the sequence defintion and after directly solving for the limit $l=\dfrac{1}{x+l}$ i.e. $l^2+lx-1=0$ i.e $l=\dfrac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$, with $x=1$  and the  'minus' solution you find the gold ratio expansion.

Comment: A common notation for continued fractions is $[a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots]$. In your case, you'd have $[0; x, x, x, \ldots]$, or, if you like, simply $[0; \bar x].$ The Wikipedia page doesn't seem to list the $\bar x$ notation, but I think it's useful and clear.

Comment: You can use \cfrac in LaTeX for continued fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [continued fractions](https://brilliant.org/wiki/continued-fractions/) and see that the notation you require is $[0;x,x,x,…]$ or $[0;\overline{x}]$, which indicates that the continued fraction has a period of length $1$ (as user2661923 points out).

Comment: Or $~[0;\overline{x}],~$ which indicates that the continued fraction has a period of length $1$.

Comment: @user2661923 sure, adding it!